# How to find x,y coordinates on a circle in Android

Tags: android, coordinates

I am drawn a circle in android and want to draw something on its edge at a particular angle. 
I know the radius, I know the angle measures from the horizontal (x-axis):

The normal math formula to calculate the respective x,y on the circle is

```
x = x0 + r * cos(theta)
y = y0 + r * sin(theta)
```

But the problem is that the coordinate system android starts at 0,0 on the left top and then increases as we go down or right.

So how would the formula change when calculating x,y on the edge of the circle at an angle?
Is there some other way to find x,y on the edge of the circle in android?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In normal cartesian coordinates, theta is measured starting from the positive x axis and increases as you rotate in an anti-clockwise direction.

However since the Y axis is inverted in the coordinate system used for the canvas in android, you need to adjust your Y equation to suit:

perimiter_X_coord = center_X_coord **+** r * cos(theta)
perimiter_Y_coord = center_Y_coord **-** r * sin(theta)

Also, remember if you are using `Math.cos()` or `Math.sin()`, they expect the angle in Radians. So if you have the angle in degrees, you will need to convert with:

```
angle_in_radians = angle_in_degrees * (Math.PI / 180)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you basically need to draw a tangent to the circle ?
http://www.mathopenref.com/tangent.html

Comment: i am but i am trying to calculate the x and y points of the tangent

Comment: exactly. Use the Pythagoras theorm